# golangのアレイと取り扱いについて

Tags: go

golangで使用するアレイの取り扱いについて質問させていただきます。

サンプルコードの後に、詳しい質問をさせていただきます。

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    x := []int{1,2,3}
    y := x

    var z []int
    for _, v := range x {
        z = append(z, v)
    }

    x[1] = 4
    fmt.Println(x)
    fmt.Println(y)
    fmt.Println(z)
}
```

コードの中では、まずxというアレイを作成します。そのアレイを別の方法で２つのアレイ(y, z)にコピーしています。
yはそのままコピーし、zはアレイの各要素をひとつづつコピーして作成します。

その後xの中身だけを変更し、すべてのアレイをPrintしているだけです。

質問ですが、
なぜyアレイも同時に変更されてしまうのでしょうか？
また、yのように作成したアレイもxとはシンクロさせない方法はあるのでしょうか？

ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 4):

質問では1次元配列を対象としていますが、コピーの対象が多次元配列の場合、`[...]` 表記(コンパイラに配列の要素数を計算させる)が使えない事があります。

例えば、以下の様な2次元配列を考えてみますと、

```golang
x := [...][2]int{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
y := x
```

この場合は全ての要素がコピーされることになります。

しかし、以下の様に各要素の配列のサイズが異なる場合に、同じ要領で `[...][...]int` として定義するとコンパイルエラーになります。

```golang
x := [...][...]int{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}}

use of [...] array outside of array literal
```

そこで `[...][]int` としてしまうと、スライスの配列として定義されますので、スライスとしてコピーされる(shallow copy)事になります。

```golang
x := [...][]int{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}}
y := x
x[1][0] = 4
=>
x: [[1 2] [4 4 5] [6 7 8 9]]
y: [[1 2] [4 4 5] [6 7 8 9]]
```

要素の最大サイズを指定するという方法もありますが、

```golang
x := [...][4]int{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}}
y := x
x[1][0] = 4
=>
x: [[1 2 0 0] [4 4 5 0] [6 7 8 9]]
y: [[1 2 0 0] [3 4 5 0] [6 7 8 9]]
```

となってしまいます。

この様な多次元配列/スライスをコピー(deep copy)するには以下の方法があります。

- deepcopy パッケージを使う

  [mohae/deepcopy](https://github.com/mohae/deepcopy)

```golang
    x := [][]int{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}}
    y := deepcopy.Iface(x).([][]int)
    x[1][0] = 4
    =>
    x: [[1 2] [4 4 5] [6 7 8 9]]
    y: [[1 2] [3 4 5] [6 7 8 9]]
```

- ループ処理で要素ごとにコピーする

```golang
    x := [][]int{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}}
    y := make([][]int, len(x))
    for i, v := range x {
      y[i] = make([]int, len(v))
      copy(y[i], v)
    }
    x[1][0] = 4
    =>
    x: [[1 2] [4 4 5] [6 7 8 9]]
    y: [[1 2] [3 4 5] [6 7 8 9]]
```

Comment: 返信が遅くなりまして、すみません。
deepcopy パッケージというパッケージがあるのですね。勉強になります。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

`[]int{1,2,3}`はスライスリテラルと呼ばれ、配列ではなく配列を参照するスライスを作成します。`y`に`x`を代入した場合、配列はコピーされず`y`と`x`は同じ配列を指します。

```
x := []int{1,2,3}    // 配列を作成してそのスライスを代入
y := x               // スライスをコピー
                     // x, y の型は []int (スライス)
```

配列を直接作成したい場合は、配列リテラル`[...]int{1,2,3}`または`[3]int{1,2,3}`を使用してください。

```
x := [...]int{1,2,3} // 配列を作成
y := x               // 配列をコピー
                     // x, y の型は [3]int (配列)
```

参考: http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: ありがとうございます。サイズ指定で配列を作成していてコードで、以前問題がありましたので、現在作成中のコードでは、配列をすべてスライスリテラルに変更していました。参考webで配列リテラルは勉強していましたが、スライスリテラルとの違いなどは完全に理解していなかったようです。再度勉強します。ご教授ありがとうございました。